# Understanding the difference between relations and functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, math-history

$R=\{(1,2),(1,3)\}$ is a relation but not function.

The logic for this is that if the first element of every ordered pair must remain different, then it is said to be function. Otherwise, it's just a relation.

My question is what is the background of this distinction?

Comment: It is just a convenient definition.

Comment: Think of a relation as a mapping of the first element in the ordered pair to the second element in that pair. In your example, given the relation R, $1$ is mapped to $2$, *and* $1$ is mapped to $3$. A function requires that every input value (from a given domain) has exactly one output value. So, the given relation cannot be a function, because since $f(1)$ is not well-defined. We can't tell whether $f(1) = 2$ or $f(1) = 3$. So it fails to be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the reason is "historical".

*Function* is a typical mathematical concept and has its origin in the idea of "recipe" or "procedure" which, taking an *input* $x$ "produce" an *output* $y$.

Paradigmatic examples are the simple mathematical functions like : "double of __" (i.e. $y = 2 \times x$), "square of __" (i.e. $y = x^2$).

The concept of *relation* is easily encountered outside of mathematics; we are all accostumed with everyday relations like : "__ is father of ..." or "__ is to the left of ...".

Only in modern times (about one century ago), the adoption of set-theoretic language in mathematics, gives us the opportunity of "modelling" relations as set of *ordered pairs* and thus to define functions simply as a "special" kind of relations : those satisying the "functionality" property :

> a *relation* $R$ such that : for $x_1Ry_1$ and $x_2Ry_2$, if $y_1 \ne y_2$, then $x_1 \ne x_2$, is called a *function*.